# Is writing of int32 atomic operation in Go?

Tags: java, go, concurrency, integer, atomic

I know that in Java writing of `int` (32bit) is an atomic operation. What about Go? Can go-routine be aborted in the middle when writing to `int32`, e.g. after writing first 16 bits?

Comment: Note that there's a lot more to atomicity than the question of whether the operation can be aborted mid-way. There's also the question of whether another thread might see the incomplete operation.

Comment: See [Benign Data Races: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to guarantee atomicity is to use the [`atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package, which is great for `int32`, and many other basic types. For more complex data types, you'll have to use other synchronization mechanisms, because atomicity may not be possible.